# Regular Expression replace expression for credit card in logback.xml

Tags: xml, layout, logback, regex-lookarounds

I want to perform masking on any number of length 12 to 16 in logs.

Masking should be like:

1. For 12 digits (657854377864) - XXXXXXXX7864
2. For 16 digits (7843657854377864)   - 7843XXXXXXXX7864
3. For 13, 14 and 15 digits -- similar to 12 digits

if I use below configuration:

```
<pattern>
  %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) - %replace(%msg{'\d{12,16}','XXXX'}%n
      </pattern>
  </encoder>
```

it converts all digits into XXXX - is there any way to print first 4 and last 4 digits as it is in the logs using regex in log file itselt

Answer (score 0):

You need two regex replacements:

```
%replace(  
  %replace(%msg){
      "(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{12,15}$))\d(?=\d{4,}$)", "X"
  })
  {"(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{16}$)(\d{4}))\d(?=\d{4,}$)", "$1X"}%n
```

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xfq9Y7/2) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xfq9Y7/3/)

**Regex #1**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{12,15}$))` - matches the end of the preceding match or a start of a string that is 12 to 15 digit chunk
- `\d` - matches a digit
- `(?=\d{4,}$)` - that is followed with 4 or more digits till the end of string.

The replacement is a mere `X` since the regex only consumes one single digit.

**Regex #2**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{16}$)(\d{4}))` - two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)` - end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?=\d{16}$)(\d{4})` - start of string that only contains 16 digits and then capturing into Group 1 any four first digits (this value is referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern)
- `\d(?=\d{4,}$)` - a digit that is followed with 4 or more digits till the end of string.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but not able to mask  --
RegEx pattern in logback-spring.xml

<layout class="com.example.demo.MaskingPatternLayout">
    <maskPattern>${keys}</maskPattern>
    <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %replace(%replace(%msg){"(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{12,15}$))\d(?=\d{4,}$)", "X"}){"(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d{16}$)(\d{4}))\d(?=\d{4,}$)", "$1X"}%n</pattern>
</layout>


In Logs -
testing random number 16 digit : 7654004986396403
testing random number 15 digit : 765400498639640

no masking in logs

Comment: @inderjeetsingh My regexps require the whole string to be equal to a number you mask. Is it the case? If not, replace `^` and `$` with `\b`.

Comment: - Yes, My whole string is equal to a number . For Example - testing random number 16 digit : 7654004986396403 testing random number 15 digit : 765400498639640 but these numbers are not getting masked. (7654004986396403 & 765400498639640 )